# Бот для группы ВК

Tags: python, бот

Вопрос таков, как сделать так, чтобы в случае отключения интернета, бот не вырубался, а ждал пока интернет включится? Бот написан на python 3.7 с использованием vk_api

Comment: Обработать соответствующее исключение.

Comment: зациклить таймаут

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    try:
        ## Ваш код
    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]